# Is it possible to integrate an HDInsight cluster with on-premises AD?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-hdinsight, apache-ranger

I've tried domain joined HDInsight cluster by integrating the HDInsight with Azure AD. I would like to know, if this integration can also support On-prem AD ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot connect an HDInsight cluster to the on-prem AD.

Currently, Azure HDInsight support ADDS based configuration.

For more details, refer “[Plan Azure domain-joined Hadoop clusters in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/domain-joined/apache-domain-joined-architecture)”.

Comment: You say no, but a line in the docs says *When integrating HDInsight with Active Directory, HDInsight cluster nodes are domain-joined to an AD domain.*.

Comment: @juunas The document talks about Azure Active Directory, not about on-premise Active Directory.

Comment: There are very few mentions of Azure AD on that page. It says requirements for setup are some things in on-prem AD + connectivity to DCs. It sounds quite possible even without AAD DS. But if that is wrong, then the documentation is quite confusing.